# Why do my particles grow outside the density vertex group?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I made a particle hair system and a vertex group for control its density, but it doesn't seem to have any influence.[image][image]
as you can see in the picture, hairs grow everywhere. I checked if I weight paint the same texture as I use and I don't know, what other reason this could have. I also noticed, that if i add interpolated (doesn't change anything if it is simple children) children, everything works all right, but not in particle edit mode. I tried rendering it and the rendered image doesn't have any hair outside the density group.

Comment: More information Please. Please show all vertex groups.  In edit mode. Select None. Then select all the member of the vertex group that appears in the density of the particles system.  If you have multiple vertex groups make sure you are editing the correct vertex group.

Comment: Try selecting the vertices of the head in edit mode and removing them from the vertex group.

Comment: PGmath - I tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: In the second image with that selection of the vertex group .... when you move the selection far .... is the selection what you think it should be?

Comment: what do you mean - move far?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One vertex group.

[image]

The other vertex group.

If you have multiple vertex group make sure you are viewing and editing the correct one.

Also make sure your blue color is exactly blue.  Paint it again to be sure.  Zoom in from different rotation angles for nooks and cranies.  Rotate the model so you are always facing the mesh face directly while painting.  Delete the vertex group, create it again, and use the new name in the Particle System.

Comment: I checked, if I am editing the correct one (this was in the question). I am.